# Capture http_referer no matter which landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-referer

Right now, I capture http_referrer within each of my controller actions, such as:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    referer = request.referer
  end
```

However, I would like to capture the referer no matter which page use lands on. How should I do that? One idea I have is to override ApplicationController to capture and save it to session. But I am not sure if this is a good way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`